# 2 Access queries on same Excel WorkBook different Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to export 2 `Access` queries to the same `Excel` `WorkBook` so query 1 goes to `Sheet1` and query 2 goes to `Sheet2`.  I am using `Access` & `Excel` 2010

I am using the following code

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' ExportToExcel
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function ExportToExcel()
On Error GoTo ExportToExcel_Err

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "TRERequired_Summary", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\Test\TRERequired_Summary.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityScreen
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "TRERequired", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\Test\TRERequired_Summary.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityScreen


ExportToExcel_Exit:
    Exit Function

ExportToExcel_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume ExportToExcel_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: And what happens when you run that?

Comment: you can try transferspreadsheet instead of the output to method. i think it has an optional worksheet name argument

Answer (score 0):

One over-writes the other. Try this:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "TRERequired_Summary", "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\Test\TRERequired_Summary.xls", True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "TRERequired", "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\Test\TRERequired_Summary.xls", True
```